# Subtle Differences between Analiticity and differentiability at a point

Tags: complex-analysis

I am stuck on the second part of this problem .Prove that the function $f(z)=|z|^4$ is differentiable , but not analytic at $z=0$. I can do the differentiability since $f(z)=(x^2+y^2)^2$ and hence at $z=0$ , we get that $f'(z)=0$ .But analytic at $z=0$ means that there exixts a neighbourhood of $z=0$ at all points of which $f'(z)$ exists , but why cannot we find such a neighbourhood around $z=0$ here???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because the Cauchy-Riemann equations $$ x^3+xy^2 = 0, \qquad x^2y+y^3=0$$are satisfied only for $z = 0$ and not in any neighbourhood of $0$. Recall that CR-equations + $f$ continuous $\iff f$ holomorphic/analytic. The $\implies$ side fails here.

Comment: +1. I add that in particular they fail along the axes. Though you should probably clarify that the implication more or less goes both ways.

Comment: Good that you point that! In fact we can say that the CR equations fail in any neighbourhood of $0$ *because* they fail along the axes. :)

Comment: Hi and thanks everbody for the answers , but I still do not understand why is it that the CR Equations fail along the axes ...Sorry if this is an elementary question

Comment: When we say that they fail along the axes, we of course are excluding $0$ of this analysis. Make $x = 0$ and suppose that $y \neq 0$. Then the CR equations fail. On the other hand, suppose $x \neq 0$ and make $y = 0$. Then the CR equations fail again.

Comment: Sorry but I still do not see it , is this analysis only for this particular problem ??

Comment: If $f = u+iv$, the CR equations are $u_x = v_y$ and $u_y = -v_x$. In your case, $v \equiv 0$, so $v_x = v_y = 0$, and we get what I stated in my answer above. We want to check when the equations will hold - it happens that they work for zero. However, any neighbourhood of zero will contain points of the axes. And for these points, the CR equations fails. For example, a point in the real axis, different from zero is of the form $(x,0)$, with $x \neq 0$. In the same way for the other axes.

Comment: I see , so since the derivative of f(z)=4x(x^2+y^2) and this equals the partial of u with respect to x , at (x,0) we do not get zero which again by CR is the partial of v with respect to y ....Thanks for your answer

Comment: Just be careful.. $f(z) = (x^2+y^2)^2 = x^4+2x^2y^2+y^4$. You go from here.